# Generic type of object value parameter

Tags: generics, typescript, types, typescript2.0

```typescript
function getValues<T, U extends { [key: string]: T }>(object: U): T[] {
    // ...
}

const test = { a: 123, b: 234 };
const values = getValues(test);
```

In the above code, I expect `values` to be of type `number[]`, but the actual type is `{}[]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type for this `{ a: 123, b: 234 }` object is:

```
{ a: number; b: number; }
```

And not

```
{ [key: string]: number }
```

You can do:

```
const test = { "a": 123, "b": 234 } as { [key: string]: number };
```

To tell the compiler that it's indeed what you want.
But even then you still won't get the type you want for `values`:

```
const values = getValues(test); // type of values {}[]
```

You should do:

```
function getValues<T>(object: { [key: string]: T }): T[] {
    return null;
}

const test = { "a": 123, "b": 234 } as { [key: string]: number };
const values = getValues(test);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20getValues%3CT%3E(object%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20%7B%20%22a%22%3A%20123%2C%20%22b%22%3A%20234%20%7D%20as%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20values%20%3D%20getValues(test)%3B))

Comment: Great, thanks, this works. `test` does not need to be cast to `{ [key: string]: number }` though, because TypeScript 2 infers the fact that all values are of type `number` and correctly matches the signature of the function. Your example will work without the cast in TypeScript 2.

Comment: Right. Wasn't aware you're using typescript 2, but I'm glad you can remove the ugly assertion.